# A Scalar SubQuery Issue - Handle Multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation with a query that I built that has a query in the select statement (I believe it is called a scalar subquery). AS you know, when using a subquery in the Select statement....at least the only way I know how...can only handle one value returned.

Anyway, I am trying to pull back in the subquery the date of an appointment type that 99% of our customers only have once. However, there are situations where that 1% have had two or more of those appointments. I only need the latest date. Can someone help me with the logic to deal with situations of multiple rows and only grab the latest date.

```
(SELECT SSUSED_1.usedate
 FROM SS AS SS_1
 INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
 WHERE MEMBERS.memid = SS_1.memid AND SS_1.productid = 326 AND SSUSED_1.transactiontype = 'Use') AS SecondUsed
```

Comment: Can you show the full query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can simply use [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx)?

```
SELECT MAX(SSUSED_1.usedate)
FROM SS AS SS_1
INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
WHERE MEMBERS.memid = SS_1.memid AND SS_1.productid = 326 AND SSUSED_1.transactiontype = 'Use'
```